# .html fails to render .js react external file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So, I am just starting to learn about HTML, CSS, javaScript and React. I am trying to render a simple "hello world" into the browser. So, straight to the point:

My code (index.html) so far looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <meta name = "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <title>New project</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
  class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
      return <div>helo world</div>
    }
  }
  ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById("root")
  );
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And it renders beautifully into the browser. Now, I want to go a little further, so my next step is to put the `App` into a separate file. This is, I make a `application.js` file in the same folder. Now my `index.html` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <meta name = "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <title>New project</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel", src="application.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my `application.js` looks like this:

```
class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return <div>HELLLOO</div>
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById("root")
);
```

When I save the new files and refresh my browser (chrome), nothing gets rendered. What is going on? What am I doing wrong?. Do I have to set something in my PC before trying to work with separate flies?. Any help would be welcome. Thanks in advance. Cheers!

Comment: You might have a typo, I see a comma in that script tag. Also are you using a webserver or just opening html files in the browser?

Comment: @RajaBilal yes. Indeed. I had a typo with the comma. But still gets the same (nothing rendered). I am only typing: ```mysuer:$ chrome index.html``` in the console. How can I do it differently?. Thanks for answering btw

Comment: I think that will not work with the babel standalone script. You will have to move away from babel standalone and use something like webpack to transpile the scripts. Babel standalone can not follow and run src attributes.

Comment: @Daantje so there is no way to render a .html file to the browser from the console while using Babel?

Comment: If you check the docs; https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone "If you're using Babel in production, you should normally not use @babel/standalone. Instead, you should use a build system running on Node.js, such as Webpack, Rollup, or Parcel, to transpile your JS ahead of time." So there is a way, but not with the standalone version.